No authentication handler is registered for the scheme
Getting this error and am in middlle of nowhere ---->
System.InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'You do not have permission to access this resource.'. The registered schemes are: Negotiate, Windows. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("You do not have permission to access this resource.",...)?
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});


app.Run();


More suitable to post to Stack Overflow if you want others to review source code.
